# Will a parallel capacitor short a resistor?

Tags: analog, dc

[image: i]

In the configuration above, SOL_IN is the rectified output of a solar panel (so dc).

What's more important is R1, which is a low resistance sense resistor used to measure the current from the solar panel. I'm concerned that the capacitor will charge to the voltage at SOL_IN and hence short circuit the resistor since there will be no voltage drop across it.

Is this reasoning correct?

(R1 = 0.15 Ohms, C1 = 1 uF)

EDIT: Line is going to load, not GPIO as originally stated.

Comment: no, that's not what "shorten" means! Shorten means *bypass* a component so that current can flow without any impedance. There's no bypassing here.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to measure over R1. If GPIO is configured as a high impedance microcontroller input, there will be nearly zero current flow, apart from a short peak while the cap is loading.

Comment: Sorry, it is going to the load and not to a microcontroller. R1 is trying to measure the current to the load.

Answer (score 2):

The GPIO pin of your micro-controller is an high-impedance input. It will allow little to no current to flow through the circuit. On average, the capacitor will not let the current go through either. As drawn, your circuit will only measure the current used to charge or discharge the capacitor, a pulse that will last: $$\tau = R \cdot C = 150 ns$$ (the [RC time constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC_time_constant)), when the voltage change. To measure the current with M1, you need to add a load to the ground where you connect the GPIO.

Comment: Sorry, the line is going to the load and not to a microcontroller. If the input is DC, the capacitor should charge to this voltage I think?

Comment: @555 Yes, in about 150ns to reach 63%. The capacitor will smooth change in load current below this time.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitor will charge to the voltage you have on the load (including the wiring). The resistor R1 will create an additional voltage drop (that's the whole purpose of a shunt resistor).
So on the right side of the resistor you will have the load voltage \$V_{load} = V_{C1}\$ and on the left side of the resistor you will have \$V_{load} + V_{R1}\$.

**This means, that the voltmeter M1 will measure the voltage drop over the resistor \$V_{R1} = R_1 \cdot I_R\$.**

You should be aware, that you want to choose your shunt quite small to reduce power losses and heating of the resistor. This will make the voltage drop quite low, so you will need a sensitive voltage measurement.